# Very long postgresql simple explain (without analyse)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, explain, postgresql-11

In order to understand why a query was slow,  I performed an analyse on it... Though, I don't understand why the explain query take several minutes.. (well, I had to cancel the explain query because I didn't get the result after letting it run several minutes).

Postgresql server version : PostgreSQL 11.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit

so the explain was like :

```
 explain select myfield from my_view where myconditions ;
```

without analyse, verbose, etc..

When querying pg_stat_activity,  I didn't see any 'lock' (wait_event_type and wait_event where 'null') and state was 'active' for this explain.

This is a production server where current trafic was handled (without problem) - well, tranfic doesn't use this query.  When executing  the query I want to analyse, I have to wait for more than 10 minutes to get the answer.

The query is made on a view that make a 'union' between one hot table, and an equivalent in structure, but partitionned.  Size of hot table is about 300GB  - and partitionned table has got  are about 20 children. Total size of partitions is about 600GB, with partition from 5GB to 100 GB.

Is there something that could explain why the plan isn't returned right away  ?

- EDIT :
  when executing an explain just on the hot table,  answer is give immediately.
  when executing the explain just on partition table, also the response was very fast.
  while,  what's very long is the explain with the query where the 'from' part is on the view that make a 'union' on these two tables  (the hot table and the partitionned table)

EDIT 2 :   result of explain (verbose, summary), of the query, as requested (I did my best to anonymize the query without altering the important part -- I didn't change any measures)

```
 Hash Left Join  (cost=8.09..11.82 rows=2 width=585)
   Output: a, b, c, rid, creation_date
   Inner Unique: true
   Hash Cond: (traffic.msg_action = ddd.rid)
   ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=6.88..10.54 rows=2 width=441)
         Output: traffic.a, traffic.b, traffic.c, traffic.rid, traffic.creation_date
         Hash Cond: (sys_sysapp_sys_application.sysapp_app_id = traffic.msg_app_id)
         Filter: (sys_sysapp_sys_application.sysapp_del_date IS NULL)
         ->  Seq Scan on general_sys_sys.sys_sysapp_sys_application  (cost=0.00..3.19 rows=119 width=25)
               Output: f1, f2, f3
         ->  Hash  (cost=6.86..6.86 rows=2 width=428)
               Output: traffic.a, traffic.b, traffic.c, traffic.rid, traffic.creation_date
               ->  Append  (cost=0.57..6.86 rows=2 width=428)
                     ->  Index Scan using idx_traffic_creation_date_210713 on myappli.traffic  (cost=0.57..2.60 rows=1 width=465)
                           Output: traffic.a, traffic.b, traffic.c, traffic.rid, traffic.creation_date
                           Index Cond: ((traffic.msg_creation_date >= '2021-08-01 05:25:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (traffic.msg_creation_date <= '2021-08-01 05:34:59'::timestamp without time zone))
                           Filter: (((traffic.c)::text = '777'::text) AND (traffic.m = '28'::smallint) AND (traffic.t = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::smallint[])))
                     ->  Index Scan using traffic_histo_y2021m08_msg_creation_date_idx on myappli_histo.traffic_histo_y2021m08  (cost=0.43..4.25 rows=1 width=392)
                           Output: traffic_histo_y2021m08.a, traffic_histo_y2021m08.b, traffic_histo_y2021m08.c, traffic_histo_y2021m08.rid, traffic_histo_y2021m08.creation_date, 
                           Index Cond: ((traffic_histo_y2021m08.msg_creation_date >= '2021-08-01 05:25:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (traffic_histo_y2021m08.msg_creation_date <= '2021-08-01 05:34:59'::timestamp without time zone))
                           Filter: (((traffic_histo_y2021m08.msg_c)::text = '777'::text) AND (traffic_histo_y2021m08.msg_type = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::smallint[])))
   ->  Hash  (cost=1.09..1.09 rows=9 width=34)
         Output: ddd.resac_label, ddd.rid
         ->  Seq Scan on general_sys_sys.sys_resac_res_action ddd  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=9 width=34)
               Output: ddd.r, ddd.rid
 Planning Time: 1844806.025 ms
(26 rows)
```

EDIT 3 :
The view 'my_view' that is executed by my query is like this

```
create or replace my_view as 
select a, b, c from myappli.traffic
UNION ALL
select a, b, c from myappli_histo.traffic_partitionned_parent_table
```

And the query is usually like this

```
select a, b, c from my_view where c between '20210801 000000' and '20210802 000000'
```

Comment: Either there ate extremely many partitions, so the planner has to work a very long time, or there is a bug, or there is data corruption.

Comment: Can you show us the plan generated using `explain (verbose, summary) ...`? That will show some more information about the planning time

Comment: thanks - I inserted the result of the exec plan as requested -- for first question, there are only 20 partitions or so.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I added queries and view structure too

Comment: The current bug fix release of v11 is REL_11_14.  Maybe your problem has been fixed in the last 18 months.

Comment: Indeed - even if last version available in Aws Aurora has same behaviour,  switching to version 12  fix this problem. with pg 12 and 13,  the explain / plan is executed right away..    thank you @jjanes

Comment: thank you very much @jjanes - it helped me a lot.   indeed, worked better after upgrading.